# Why is the imaginary part of the Breit-Wigner propagator given by the total decay width?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, propagator

The optical theorem links the imaginary part of the forward scattering amplitude to the total decay width of a particle: $\mathrm{Im}\,M_{i\to i} = m\Gamma_{tot}$. Here $\Gamma_{tot} = \frac{1}{2m} \sum_x |M_{i\to x}|^2$. My QFT lecturer told us that the Breit-Wigner propagator $\frac{i}{p^2-m^2+im\Gamma_{tot}}$ follows from that. How?

I tried to use the LSZ formula to replace the forward amplitude to the propagator. However I don't even know if the LSZ formula is applicable here (due to the complex mass).  If one can use it I find something like (for a scalar particle) $iM_{i\to i} \sim (p^2 - m^2)^2 \cdot \frac{i}{p^2-m^2+i\varepsilon}$ which should simply vanish for on-shell particles, whether or not $m$ has an imaginary part.

So how does the Breit-Wigner propagator follows from the optical theorem? In particular why is the $\Gamma$ in the Breit-Wigner propagator the same as in the optical theorem?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Breit%E2%80%93Wigner_distribution) useful?

Comment: Sorry, but how does anything on this Wikipedia page answer this question?  :D

Comment: It sends you to L Brown's friendly derivation to the generic propagator of an unstable particle, and whence the relativistic Breit-Wigner formula. I did not stick to the somewhat off-mainstream twists and turns of your proposed path to it.

Comment: This just explains that a complex pole of propagator is related to a exponential decay of the propagator. This does not show that the $\Gamma$ in the propagator is actually the total decay width as calculated in scattering theory: $\Gamma_{tot} = \frac{1}{2m} \sum_x |M_{i \to x}|^2$.

Comment: I took you to Lowell Brown's (6.314-6.3.23), but I can't make you drink... Perhaps if you took that *primary* section into consideration in restructuring your question you might have better luck.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Ehm... your answer is really not useful at all. SE is not about thinking that you take someone to the source; it's about explaining and giving concrete answers.

Comment: Answer? We hardly got to the question! Thanks for the advice. I have so far failed to understand SE as a bypass of standard material detailed in texts and reading them to the student who should have gone through them in their course. This is a clear-cut non-question that should have not been asked, or asked with more detail about where the mental block resides...

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/333491/breit-wigner-vs-propagator?rq=1).